# WSO2 Publisher - Publish Button Disabled

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a WSO2 Api Manager running locally and I can't publish an api because the button is disabled.

https://localhost:9443/publisher

[image]

I'm trying to publish with "admin" user and I've checked the roles in carbon and "admin" user
has all roles.

Does anybody know why the button is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify Business Plans for the API by going to the Subscriptions section in the API or during the initial API creation step. The Business plans are crossed out in the above screenshot because you have not defined them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to publish an API in wso2am-3.X.X, you have to provide the "business plan" and "endpoints".
If any of the above requirements are not satisfied, it is indicated on the lifecycle/overview page, and you need to navigate to relevant sections and provide the missing information such as endpoint URL and business plans.
[image]
Fig 1: Lifecycle page with conditions to publish the API

[image]
Fig 2: Overview page with conditions to publish the API

In your situation, you have provided the endpoint but have not selected the business plan. Please select the business plan, save it and try to publish the API

For more details please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/publish-api/publish-an-api/